# How do I make theme suggestions for pagers?

Tags: theming

I am trying to create `theme suggestions` function for pagers in my *.theme. Is this possible in Drupal 8? If it is possible, what is wrong with the following code? Is `suggestions_pager_alter` the right way to access the hook call so I can add a theme suggestion to a page, so I can override the template. I am not worried about the functions logic.

```
function mytheme_suggestions_pager_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  // Add template suggestions based on the current view mode.
   print_r(); exit;

}
```

Comment: There isn't much in the function you are showing. If you are asking if that is the correct way to check a hook is invoked, then no, it isn't. A part that, is there something more specified you are worried about?

Comment: If you want to check if the function ran  use `drupal_set_message('yes it works!!!', 'warning');` instead of `print_r(); exit;`. You should get the yellow warning message if it ran.

Answer (score 0):

`mytheme_suggestions_pager_alter` is the correct way to use the hook. The issue was my pager in the view footer was not working and this stop the function from being called